# Trouble getting and setting the fill color for entire row

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I have a code block which will set some Value in a cell of a certain column upon a certain condition. All good there.
Currently the script is set to color only that one cell.
I in fact want to color fill the entire row.

Not sure how to use the declared variables in the loop to get the column range and color it.

```
 // Iterate over every row looking for similarities from the other worksheet.
 let rowsLentgh = table.getRowCount();
 let rows = range.getValues();
 for (let i = 0; i < rowsLentgh; i++) {
   let row = rows[i];
   const exhibitorName = row[companiesToCheckIndex]
   const exhibitorDomainNames = row[domainNamesToCheckIndex]
   const exhibitorLinkedinDomain = row[linkedinDomainsToCheckIndex]

   // Look at each key provided for a matching Company Name.
   for (let keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < keysObject.length; keyIndex++) {
     let companyEntity = keysObject[keyIndex];
     if (companyEntity.companyName === exhibitorName) {
       overallMatch = true
       range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).setValue("Matched");        
       range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).getFormat().getFill().setColor("FF0000");
       range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).getFormat().getFont().setColor("000000");        
       break;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code lines

```js
range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).getFormat().getFill().setColor("FF0000");
range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).getFormat().getFont().setColor("000000");
```

If `range` is the data body range of table, it doesn't include the header row. `i+1` is needed in the first snipppet.

```js
table.getRange().getRow(i+1).getFormat().getFill().setColor("FF0000");
table.getRange().getRow(i+1).getFormat().getFont().setColor("000000");
```

OR

```js
range.getRow(i).getFormat().getFill().setColor("FF0000");
range.getRow(i).getFormat().getFont().setColor("000000");
```

Comment: Hey there.

So (before you posted) I was able to do a solution like this.


        
`let rowRange = table.getRange().getRow(i+1);
 rowRange.getFormat().getFill().setColor("FF0000");
 range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).setValue("Matched");        
 range.getCell(i, screeningColumnIndex).getFormat().getFont().setColor("000000");      
 break;
      }`

The funny thing is that I had to use i + 1 otherwise the colored row is the one above the actual one that is set value to "Matched"!

Any clue?

Comment: Please have a look my updated reply.